# Is it possible to sign the pdf inside my app instead of redirecting to docusing

Tags: docusignapi

I am having the requirement where the already notification pdf sent to users by my app now I want just the user can sign that document inside the app only he should not be redirected to the docusign for signing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. You can embed the signing session (the URL you get form the API call) inside an iframe in your app. You will have to ensure that the browser allows iframes with cookies from "3rd parties" but it should work.